# Duplicate removal based on blank cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a list that has ID's in Column A, agencyID in columnB, Admit date in Column C and a program in column D and a start date in Column E.

Column F has End dates.

Is there a way in Excel to remove duplicate rows based on the ID, AgencyID, Admit date, program and start date columns A, B,C,D,E AND blank cells in Column F for the end dates?

```
     A          B         C          D              E            F
 0901652    005699560   8/5/2012    SummerCamp  8/5/2012    
 0901652    005699560   8/5/2012    SummerCamp  8/5/2012    5/16/2016
```

I have tried using the remove Duplicates functionality in excel but this functionality removes some of the values with blanks on column F. I have also tried the function

```
=COUNTIF($A$2:$F$2,A2)
```

but it is not consistent since I get a 0 on the record above and I know this is a duplicate.

```
    A          B         C          D              E            F          G
   0901652  005699560   8/5/2012    SummerCamp  8/5/2012                   0
  0901652   005699560   8/5/2012    SummerCamp  8/5/2012    5/16/2016      0
```

I should only get

```
     A          B         C          D              E            F         
   0901652  005699560   8/5/2012    SummerCamp  8/5/2012
```

Comment: Do you want to keep F with a blank, or F with a date?

Comment: keep F with a blank.

Answer (score 0):

Select all Data:
[image: select all data]

Click Remove duplicates -> then uncheck F:
[image: uncheck F]
Press OK

end result:

[image: end result]

Answer (score 0):

Carrying you Formula which needs little corrections since you need First identify Duplicate Row then Remove them. For this, **in Column G first put Heading, Duplicates and in next Row write this Formula.**

=IF(COUNTIFS($A$2:$A2,$A2,$B$2:$B2,$B2,$C$2:$C2,$C2,$D$2:$D2,$D2,$E$2:$E2,$E2)>1,"Duplicate","Unique")

Drag the Formula till it's required. You find DUPLICATE & UNIQUE in Column G.

Then Select entire Data Range, Apply Filter and Filter Duplicates and Delete them.

Finally remove the effect of Filter Command, you find only Unique records.

**Hope this help you, in case my Solution differed just drop a Comment, I'll suggest other Solution as the issue.**